# Is the unnecessary to loop through the result of an executeSql command?

Tags: javascript, mustache

There's a lot of code here, but the question has to do with the for loop at the bottom.

```
var dbo = openDatabase('xxx','1.0','myDatabase', 1048576);
var DropTableDeferred = new $.Deferred();
var CreateTableDeferred = new $.Deferred();
var InsertDeferred = new $.Deferred();
var SelectDeferred = new $.Deferred();
dbo.transaction(function(myTrans) {
    myTrans.executeSql(
        'drop table myTable;'
        ,[]
        ,DropTableDeferred.resolve()
    );
});
DropTableDeferred.done(function() {
    dbo.transaction(function(myTrans) {
        myTrans.executeSql(
            'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable' 
            + '(xxxID Integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY'
            + ',xxxName Varchar(128)'
            + ');'
            ,[]
            ,CreateTableDeferred.resolve()
        );
    });
});
CreateTableDeferred.done(function() {
    dbo.transaction(function(myTrans) {
        myTrans.executeSql("INSERT INTO myTable(xxxID,xxxName) VALUES(1,'A')");
        myTrans.executeSql("INSERT INTO myTable(xxxID,xxxName) VALUES(2,'B')");
        myTrans.executeSql(
            "INSERT INTO myTable(xxxID,xxxName) VALUES(3,'C')",
            [],
            InsertDeferred.resolve()
        );
    });
});

InsertDeferred.done(function() {
    dbo.transaction(function(myTrans) {
        myTrans.executeSql(
            'SELECT * FROM myTable',
            [], 
            function(tx, result) {
                SelectDeferred.resolve(result);
            }
        );
    });
});

SelectDeferred.done(function(result) {
    var X = $('#result-template').html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(X);
    var data = [];

    for(var i=0;i < result.rows.length; i++) {
        data.push(result.rows.item(i));
    }
    $('ul').append(template(data));
});
```

Q: Do I need to build a data array in order to call template(data), or can I pass the result variable directly?

And by 'result variable', what I mean is: result.rows, or result.rows.item, or some other combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the value has passed directly in my html&javascript only project. In the code below, I get the results of the Sql and filling a dropdown box's options.

```
    function fillLectureFromDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM LECTURE', [], successFill, errorFill);
    }
    function successFill(tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
            var elOptNew = document.createElement('option');
            elOptNew.text = results.rows.item(i).code;
            elOptNew.value = results.rows.item(i).code;
            var elSel = document.getElementById('slExCode');
            elSel.add(elOptNew, null);  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh, well the question has to do specifically with mustache and handlebars.  Do I need to loop over my result set in order to build an array that mustache can use.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you can, but to tell you the truth, it would've taken less time for you to try it out then to post the question. Just try:

```
$('ul').append(template(result.rows));
```

Comment: Well, I have tried every combination that I can think of.  But with JavaScript, I've found that the answer is NEVER what I would have thought of.  The experts here on StackOverflow always come up with a perspective that I don't have.

Comment: I don't understand. Did this work? If not what's the problem with it?

Comment: No, it didn't work.  I had to loop through result.rows.item() building a arrData[].  What was the problem?  I don't know.  It just failed silently.

Comment: I think I know why: result.rows is an object (hash), while data = [] (Array), and the two are incompatible.